# How can I prove every positive real number has square root?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does it ask that we can express any positive real number as square root of something? like 4 is equal to square root of 16?

Comment: Start with the definition of square root, then show for an arbitrary positive real number x, there is another real number such that y is a square root for x.

Comment: More likely, one has to start with the definition of "real number".

Comment: Here is a sketch: let $y$ and $r$ be positive real numbers. Consider the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $x^r > y$. Try showing that the infimum of this set satisfies $x^r = y$.

Comment: Here is a high-powered way to do it: let $\alpha>0$ be given. Consider the function $f:[0,\alpha+1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^{2}-\alpha$. Choose some suitable values of $x$ and apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as that asked in the body.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Consider the set $\{x\in \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} \colon x^2<y\}$. By the completeness axiom, there is a least upper bound of this set, call it $x_0$.

If $x_0^2<y$, then by density of rationals, there is some rational number $q$ in $(x_0^2,y)$. Does this make sense?

If $x_0^2>y$. What happens?

So there's only one choice left.

Comment: All very true, and quite rigid, but perhaps above OP's level of understanding

Comment: I don't see how the denseness of the rationals comes into play.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

On the opposite, it is asking if any positive number is *the square* of something i.e. if

$$x=\left(\sqrt x\right)^2$$ is always possible.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not answering her question. She is asking (in the question body) whether (a) "prove that every positive number has a square root" means (b) "prove that every positive number is the square root of another number". She is not asking for a solution of (b).

Comment: @user1551: now I understand the question, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^2$ from $[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is a strictly increasing continuous function,since $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ the function is bijective,hence it's inverse is also bijective since $\sqrt{x}$ is the inverse that implies it's also surjective.This is true if the definition of square root is such that it is the inverse of the square function.

Answer (score 1):

Your title says that the problem is:

- (a) Prove that every positive number has a square root, that is, for any $y > 0$, prove that there exists $x$ such that $x^2 = y$.

Your text says:

- (b) Prove that every positive number is the square root of another number, that is, for any $z > 0$, there exists $w = z^2$.

(b) is obviously true, and does not entail (a).

How to prove (a), now? This depends on how you have introduced real numbers. I guess you did it as the closure of the set of rational numbers.

Then if you show that $x$ in (a) can be written as the limit of a sequence $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ with $f$ defined with the basic arithmetic operations, you'll be able to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

If we cheat a bit (by presupposing our claim) we can give the following justification:

Assume that $x_0\gt0$ is not a square root of any real number. Then, we can define the continuous function:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-x_0}
$$
for all real $x$. In particular, it is continuous in the segment $[0,1+x_0]$, and so must obtain its maximum there. However, the function is not bounded in that segement - a contradiction.